# Which data type should use for no of same type of data can have

Tags: mysql, database, comments

I'm using mySQL

I have confused with which data type should I use for store data

I am developing website where user can upload photos video and other can like photo video and also comment how look like photo video just like Facebook post l have following table design

Post_no ( int ) auto-increment, pk

Post ( long blob )

Post_description ( long Text )
Username ( varchar )

Likes ( big int )

Comments ( confused which data type should use)

In this table i want if 1 user upload photos so other people can comment on this photo the photos wil stored in this table & when people see photos they can write ✍️ comments & stored in this table  you can say i want to stored table in table